# Sidebar that occupies the rest of the page height, and scrolls when there are many elements inside?

Tags: css, sidebar

I need to add a sidebar, that occupies the rest of the page's height, but when there are many elements inside it scrolls on the y axis.

The problem i always get with the solutions ive seen online, is that as soon as the elements inside are taller than the page, the sidebar grows and there is no scrolling.

I have two columns, the left one with a div where it says: `Jam in your hood...` and below is the sidebar.

and on the right is a map.

How can i have the sidebar... occupy the ressting space of the page but scroll if the elements inside are taller?

[image: sidenar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sidebar thinks it's a normal, scrolling page by default, and will expand downwards. To prevent it, wrap the elements in a container with class .sidebar and add the following styles:

```
.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

This shortens the sidebar to the remaining space, and tells it to scroll any overflow that it has.